# Redirect to html page from Objective-C in phonegap

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I have to redirect my phonegap app to a specific html page after receiving push notification. I don't know how to do it from objective-c code.

I want to do something like that:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
   //redirect to html page from here.
}
```

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:theURL];`

Comment: Do you want to open this page in safari app or in a separate view in your app?

Comment: @H2CO3 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"Test.html"];        is above syntax is right?

Comment: @Greg I want to open it in my app

Comment: @Minhaj No. Just read the documentation of that method. It expects an `NSURL` instance as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new view controller, subclass of UIWebView (you can do it in the storyboard) and after that in your `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` get that view controller pass your url as a parameter and it should be fine, lets say you have your web view inside navigationController, you can do something like that:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)_window.rootViewController;
    YourWebViewController *webViewController = 
                        (YourWebViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:0];
// pass url as a parameter (you have to create property first in your YourWebViewController class)
webViewController.urlToOpen = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Bear in mind that is good to add to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I give path of my html page in www folder instead of @"http://www.google.com"